# python: check if a hostname is resolved

Tags: python, hostname

How can I have a function in python that returns 1 if the a hostname resolves and 0 if a hostname does not.

I couldn't find anything useful, any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: Returning 0/1 is very 'unpythonic' instead of True/False. It would be some extremely specific code that could even tell them apart as `1 == True`, `0 == False`, `True + True == 2`, and `sum(n % 2 == 0 for n in range(1000)) == 500`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use [`socket.gethostbyname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) for this:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
'74.125.224.198'
>>> socket.gethostbyname('foo')           # no host 'foo' exists on the network
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Your function might look like this:

```
def hostname_resolves(hostname):
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        return 1
    except socket.error:
        return 0
```

Example:

```
>>> hostname_resolves('google.com')
1
>>> hostname_resolves('foo')
0
```