# In Python, for a POST request, is it possible to obtain the ip address used for the request from the POST request object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post

For a general POST request in Python like:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
>>> type(r)
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Is it possible to obtain the ip address that was used at the time the post request was made? I have tried to look through its contents using `dir(r)` and got:

```
dir(r)
```

> ['**attrs**', '**bool**', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**',
>   '**dir**', '**doc**', '**enter**', '**eq**', '**exit**', '**format**',
>   '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getstate**', '**gt**', '**hash**',
>   '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**iter**', '**le**', '**lt**',
>   '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**nonzero**', '**reduce**',
>   '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**setstate**',
>   '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**',
>   '_content', '_content_consumed', '_next', 'apparent_encoding',
>   'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'encoding',
>   'headers', 'history', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect',
>   'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'next', 'ok',
>   'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request', 'status_code', 'text',
>   'url']

Is there something in here that might contain it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No". The actual IP resolution happens *relatively low* in the HTTP request stack and is generally not exposed (in 'any' higher-level HTTP API, regardless of language implementation).

Instead, [get the *hostname* from the url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9626596/2864740) and [resolve the extracted hostname to an IP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618118/2864740).

There is a *very brief* timing window that technically 'could' result in a different value, but it "ought to be good enough" - especially since the network name resolution is cached, and putting that much reliance on a resolved IP sounds .. funky.

(While one could resolve the IP first, and use that for the request, it would also change the HTTP host headers. So: probably not useful.)