# azure function app python requests is working fine in local but giving connection error from function app

Tags: azure, python-requests, azure-functions

I have created a function with http trigger. Inside function, i have written python code which hits rest api and return json data as response.

```python
request_headers = {"Authorization":"Api-Token {}".format(api_token)}

url = "https://<<host>>/e/54d139b9-23ee-466d-ad7a-f98e0bd8bdf4/{}?includeData=true&aggregationType=COUNT&relativeTime={}&entity={}".format(api_endpoint,relativeTime,entity)

response = requests.get(url, headers = request_headers)
return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response.json()))
```

It is running successfully in local.However the same code from function app giving below error

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<<host>>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /e/54d139b9-23ee-466d-ad7a-f98e0bd8bdf4/<<api_endpoint>>?includeData=true&aggregationType=COUNT&relativeTime=6hours&entity=<<entity>> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbe44681ac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname'))`

Can anyone help with this error?

Comment: Sounds like a simple name resolution error. Try to add some logs to print output of name resolution, run it locally and then in cloud and update the question with output. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11618198/496289

Comment: But the same code is working fine in local. What happens when i deployed the code to function app?

Comment: Great. If it works in local then use it in local! If everything worked everywhere we'll all be out of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what Kashyap mentioned in comment, it seems there is something wrong with the host name in your `url`. I test with incorrect host in my code and reproduce the same error message with yours.

So please check if the `<<host>>` is correct if you just hard code it in `url`. And if it is not hardcode, it comes from some variables (for example if it comes from application settings of your function app), please make sure if you have added the variable to application settings in your function app. Because when we deploy the function app from local to azure, the variables in "local.settings.json" will not also be deployed to function app automatically, we need to add the variable to application settings manually after deployment.

Comment: I am not using any settings here, hostname is hardcoded and api_endpoint is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Mahi May I know how long does the request take ? And how did you deploy the function from local to azure ?